# FFMPEG HLS streaming and transcoding on the fly to HTML player - video duration changes while transcoding

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I am trying to make a video streaming server and watch videos directly from web browser. The idea is to make the server to stream video from remote server, transcode with different audio format in local server, and then instantly stream to the client (this is specific way I need it to function).
This is the FFMPEG code im currently using:

```
ffmpeg -i "url" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -f hls -hls_time 60 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_flags independent_segments out.m3u8
```

The HLS stream is attached to the HTML player with hls.js and it works. However, the video duration is constantly changing while video is being transcoded. I have tried to change video duration with JS like `$('video').duration = 120;`with no luck.

How do i make the player to display the video file duration instead of stream current transcoded time?

I am also planning to implement video seeking but i am clueless. The current idea is to send seeking time to the server, terminate ffmpeg, and start from specific time. However, i think the player might get stuck on loading and will not start playing without reloading.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? At this point I'm thinking I may have to build my own video controls.

Answer (score 1):

Ffmpeg can’t write segments to the manifest before they are on disk. You will need to wait for ffmpeg to finish If you don’t want the “live like” behavior during media preparation.

Comment: Are there any other options? For example, webtor.io uses hls to stream videos and displays duration correctly. I cant figure out what kind of methed they use to transcode on the fly.

Comment: The answer on how that do that is too long for a single stack overflow post. It involves locating frame timings within the file, converting them to file offsets, converting that to pieces in the .torrent file and repackaging the media on the fly in javascript in the browse. Of it could sent the duration of the media buffer and disable seeking.

Comment: I know that they use hls and does the transcoding on the server. I still need the solution for this. If you know the answer I would gladly read it

Comment: As I said before, the answer is too complex for a single stackoverflow post. Just in time transcoding is a very difficult problem. Especially for audio. I created the just in time transcoder at mux.com. Its thousands of lines of code.